# How to include multiple servers in DFD

Tags: server, diagrams, process

I want to draw a DFD to show data in a multi server (about 10 servers) process, how the data files are passed around between servers, including schedule.

I googled and got a DFD style named "Gane and Sarson" but "datastore" in this concept does not represent servers well. ( http://dia-installer.de/shapes/Gane_and_Sarson/index.html.en ). Also I don't want to include process because that would clutter the diagram since we have to many data being passed around.

Is DFD what I am looking for or it there another way to draw this graph?

Answer (score 1):

A Dataflow diagram is too abstract for what you are talking about.
It does not care how a process is implemented.

From the DFD perspective, 
it is no different if a (sub-)process making up you system is done on one server, or on the other.
In fact, it doesn't even care if it is running on a computer, or being done manually by a human.

It also does not care about schedule.

If your DFD is too complex, then it sounds like it is too detailed.
You can always write a higher level DFD, and then a lower level DFD within a system.
Or more likely, DFD is the wrong tool for the job.